# Span class does not close in Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I've got a two Modal windows, one is for adding data, the other for editing. The following 'Modal' does work, it closes when span (x) is pressed, or any other place is clicked.

```html
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="action.php">          
     <button id="form-submit" type="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

However, this 'Modal2' does not react to close button. How is that possible? THey are in one html page, and javascript modal.js is included in `<body>` tag.

```html
 
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="action.php">          
   <input type="hidden" id= "idbs" name="idbs" />      
   <button id="form-submit" type="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

and the Javascript for span is:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var openBtn = document.getElementById("openModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: `span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]` selects the first found element only.

Comment: Ow wow. And should I copy this element and write  ("close")[1]?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to delegate the event to the closest common ancestor element. Similar you've done in `window.onclick`, just check which span is clicked, and close the corresponding modal.

Comment: Add `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute into your span. It will also help to reduce your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('Modal2');

 // Get the button that opens the modal
 var openBtn = document.getElementById("openModal");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
 // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
 /*openBtn.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "block";
 }*/

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 }
   span2.onclick = function() {
     modal2.style.display = "none";
   }
 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }else if(event.target == modal2){
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
      <div id="Modal" class="modal">
       <!-- Modal content add data -->
      <div class="modal-content gradient-border">
   <span class="close" id="span">&times;</span>
   <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="catadd.php">
     <h4 id="modal-form-header">First add</h4>
     <div class="gradient-border">
  <h5>info</h5>
         <br>
     <button id="form-submit" class="main-btn" type="submit" value="add">add</button>
        </div>
  </form>
     </div>
  </div>
       <div id="Modal2" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content edit data -->
      <div class="modal-content gradient-border">
   <span class="close" id="span2">&times;</span>
   <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="catedit.php">
     <h4 id="modal-form-header">Second add</h4>
      <div class="gradient-border">
    <h5>info</h5>
     <br>
  <input type="hidden" id= "idbs" name="idbs" />
 
          </div>
     <br>
     <button id="form-submit" class="main-btn" type="submit" value="edit">add</button>
  </form>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Basically, another js file with modal id='Modal2'... Does not help, even though it should...

Comment: how about making two different js for each modal?

Comment: @ShadowFiend I did it; the other file:

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal2');  > not working

Comment: @ShadowFiend  Nah, second one still remains unclosed. I updated  both js and html page... 
The first works fine

Comment: @upicik try looking at the gradient-border class in your first modal.. It doesn't have a closing tag when I updated your html.

Comment: @ShadowFiend it worked! Problem was in my browser, I cleared the cache and did hard refresh - it all worked. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below solution works for you. Basically, I pass Modal ID in buttons as `data` attributes.

**Note:** I assume that the modal markup structure remains the same, otherwise the code `element.parentNode.parentNode...` will not work.

On click of the button, the modal dialog is displayed (using data attribute) and on click of `span` element in the modal, I get handle to parent `div` (having Modal ID) and close it.

```js
//Display modal
function displayModal(element)
{
  var modal = document.getElementById(element.dataset.modal);
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

//Close modal
function closeDialog(element)
{
 var modalID = element.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="Modal" class="modal">
 <!-- Modal content add data -->
 <div class="modal-content gradient-border">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeDialog(this)">&times;</span>
  <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="cat.php">
   <h4 id="modal-form-header">add</h4>
   <div class="gradient-border">
    <h5>info</h5>
    <br>
    <button id="form-submit" class="main-btn" type="submit" value="add">add</button>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="Modal2" class="modal">
 <!-- Modal content edit data -->
 <div class="modal-content gradient-border">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeDialog(this)">&times;</span>
  <form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="cat.php">
   <h4 id="modal-form-header">edit </h4>
   <div class="gradient-border">
    <h5>info</h5>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="idbs" name="idbs" />

   </div>
   <br>
   <button id="form-submit" class="main-btn" type="submit" value="edit">edit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<button class="openModal" data-modal="Modal" onclick="displayModal(this)">Open modal 1</button>
<button class="openModal" data-modal="Modal2" onclick="displayModal(this)">Open modal 2</button>
```